# Set a Value as a Column Name in SQL Select

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a list of values after a select from a table:

DEPARTMENT(Table):

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| DEPT_NAME | DEPT_ID | DEPT_CITY | DEPT_TYPE |
+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|           |         |           |           |
+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now,
 my SELECT Query should be:

```
SELECT DEPT_NAME,DEPT_ID,DEPT_CITY from LOCATIONS table where (external condition);
```

Comment: so you want to take the values from one table and use them as the fields in the select part of a sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

i think this can be done using pivot table.

please check this this tutorial http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

further you can check these in SO itself,
[MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using MS SQL you can use the FOR XML Path('') statement and create dymanic sql query as followed:(I dnn't have access to other SQL Management Systems so I don't know if this would work for them.

```
DECLARE @columns varchar(255) = (select ',' + [Column] FROM (Values('DEPT_NAME'),('DEPT_ID'),('DEPT_CITY'),('DEPT_TYPE')) as tColumns([column])FOR XML PATH(''))
--select @columns

DECLARE @stmt varchar(255) = 'Select 1 as DummyColumn ' + @columns + ' from LOCATIONS table where (external condition);'
--select @stmt
EXEC(@stmt)
```

in this case I'm using 255 as the length of the variables; but you can change that to anything of your liking.

(Values('DEPT_NAME'),('DEPT_ID'),('DEPT_CITY'),('DEPT_TYPE')) as tColumns([column]) is an inline values table; you need to replace this with the correct select statement.